# The error creating app Engine's DataStore Entity within GWT app

Tags: gwt, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I try to create the entity like this:

```
DatastoreService ds = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
Entity stock = new Entity("Stock", 1);
stock.setProperty("Stock", "FCB");
ds.put(stock);
```

but keep getting the error:

> No source code is available for type com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService; did you forget to inherit a required module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## No source code is available

GWT transliterate Java to Javascript, reading it's source code and there a [limited language support](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsCompatibility.html).

What you're trying to achieve is a **Server** only operation and you're adding this operation within the client code, which will run on a browser. Neither GAE allow this or GWT has the source of these classes nor capability to do so.

#### Solution

You need to create a request to your server that will access the `DatastoreService` , the return the output to the client code.
Below a example of a properly architect GWT web application:
[image: GWT Diagram]

Comment: Maybe this library could solve this issue: https://github.com/objectify/objectify-gwt ??

Comment: Hey @TadasDavidsonas, I'm not really sure, I looked up it's source, doesn't sound production ready nor it provides source or a wrapper for `DatastoreService`, I think you will end up with the same issue. PS: I used  `Objectify` lib on one project, was nice :-)

Answer (score 2):

The error means just what it says, the GWT compiler needs access to the Java source it compiles to Javascript, and obviously `DatastoreService` is not something that should exist on the frontend - so you have an architecture issue here.

You'll need to write a proxy that can call a server component (Which in turns calls the `DatastoreService`) and returns DTOs/value objects (that you define and thus have the source for).

Cheers,